# Reading Web.Config value through CSS

Tags: javascript, css, web-config

I know that we can read the value from Web.config file through javascript.

For example,

I can read the value of "var1" by using javascript.

Can I read this value by using "CSS". Is there any code,so that we can read it through CSS itself.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot do that. However, as you already mentioned you can read it through javascript and then add it on an element or the document. Please provide your full scenario so we can help you.